# Why does getting a missing key from java.util.HashMap[Long,Long] return 0L?

Tags: java, scala, hashmap

I was playing in the scala repl and found this:

```
scala> new java.util.HashMap[Long, Long]().get(1L)
res2: Long = 0
```

Why does it return that? Java hashmaps are supposed to return null for missing keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finding the mechanism isn't too hard.

```
scala> new java.util.HashMap[Long, Long]().get(1L)
res0: Long = 0

scala> :javap -prv -
Binary file res0 contains $line3.$read$$iw$$iw$
[snip]
        17: invokestatic  #30                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToLong:(J)Ljava/lang/Long;
        20: invokevirtual #34                 // Method java/util/HashMap.get:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        23: invokestatic  #38                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.unboxToLong:(Ljava/lang/Object;)J
```

and

```
public static long unboxToLong(Object l) {
    return l == null ? 0 : ((java.lang.Long)l).longValue();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should either,

1. Use a [Scala map](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map), or
2. Check if the key is present with [containsKey(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29) like you should when you use Java.

It can't work like that in Scale, from the scala.Null [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.Null) -

> Since Null is not a subtype of value types, null is not a member of any such type. For instance, it is not possible to assign null to a variable of type scala.Int.

Comment: I know how to handle them in real code, I'm just more wondering what mechanism is at work here

Comment: Edited. But, it is not possible to assign null to a variable like that in Scala.

Answer (score 3):

In Scala, `Long` is an `AnyVal` so it cannot be null.